# Docusign bulk send using php client

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have implemented bulk send using docusign php client. I'm getting following error message

> {   "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",   "message": "Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: stream" }

when I run below source code.

```
$templateId = 'd756f973-...';
$apiClient  = $this->getDocuSignClient();

// Get Template
$templatesApi = new TemplatesApi($apiClient);
$templateDetails = $templatesApi->get($this->getAccountId(), $templateId);

// Set documents
...

// Receipient
$signer = new Signer();
$signer->setIsBulkRecipient('true');
$signer->setRecipientId('1');

$recipients = new Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners([$signer]);

// Create draft template

$envelopDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelopDefinition->setStatus('created');
$envelopDefinition->setDocuments($documents);
$envelopDefinition->setRecipients($recipients);
$envelopDefinition->setEmailSubject('Sign bulk send');

$envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$envelopSummary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($this->getAccountId(), $envelopDefinition);

// Update bulk recipients

$clients = Client::all();
$bulkRecipients = [];

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    $bulkRecipient = new BulkRecipient();
    $bulkRecipient->setEmail($client->email);
    $bulkRecipient->setName($client->first_name);

    $bulkRecipients[] = $bulkRecipient;
}

$bulkRequest = new BulkRecipientsRequest();
$bulkRequest->setBulkRecipients($bulkRecipients);

$bulkEnvelopesApi = new BulkEnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$bulkEnvelopesApi->updateRecipients($this->getAccountId(), $envelopSummary['envelope_id'], '1', $bulkRequest);
// ---------- the error message throws on above line ----------
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to update to version 4 (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/releases/tag/v4.0.0) of the PHP client. This supports our new v2.1 API which has a much improved bulk send support https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/BulkEnvelopes/BulkEnvelopes/